# Jersey - MessageBodyWriter not found application/xml ArrayList (with jersey-jaxb in war)

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jaxb, jersey

I have a Jersey controller that is returning a `List<MyPojo>` (it is actually returning an `ArrayList`. My pom includes `jersey-server` and so I am automatically getting `jersey-media-jaxb` and I have verified that my war does contain that dependency.

The endpoint is marked with:

```
@Produces(value={MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
```

When I hit it with no `accept` specified (or with `application/json`) I get back JSON with no issues. But when I specify 'accept=application/xml` I get:

`MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List<MyPoJo>`

Not sure if it matters, but I am using Spring boot but I am not using the jersey starter due to version issues.

**Update**

As a note: this worked using Spring MVC and the default output was XML.

I can't copy/paste the method but here is outline
Method:

```
@Get
@Path("/since")
@Produces(value={MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public List<MyMetadata> since(){
   return callService(paramaters);
}

// The below pre-existed me
public class MyMetadata{
    private String id;

    @JsonSerialize(using=DateTimeSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using=MyDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    private DateTime startTime;

     private List<String> ids;

     private List<OtherPojo> uuids;

     private SecurityPojo security;

     private Set<MyTuples> ads;
}
```

Comment: @peeskillet here is the question

Comment: Can you show the resource method and POJO.

Comment: @peeskillet updated

Comment: Is `MyMetadata` annotated with `@XmlRootElement` on the class?

Comment: Also I don't know if JAXB supports Java 8 Time right now. You might need a custom `XmlAdapter`. You can search for this, and you should find it. But I don't think this would cause the NoMessageBodyWriter exception. This would give you a server error which would cause a 500.

Comment: @peeskillet It is not. Spring MVC handled it fine without, is jersey jaxb different? Wouldn't the root element be the `ArrayList`? Also, I have another application where I converted a single endpoint from MVC to Jersey and it did not require the annotation on the Pojo (returned singularly, not in a list)

Comment: It's been a while since I looked through the source to get all the details of why, but I am pretty sure that it is required on all pojos. maybe something to do with JAXBContext, which requires the annotation. Either that or the messagebodywriter explicitly checks for it. Not 100% sure on the details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133016/discussion-between-john-b-and-peeskillet).

Comment: @JohnB, did you ever figure this out?  I am hitting the exact same issue on my example application: https://gitlab.com/pastdev/docker-foo-service

Comment: @Lucas My issue was that my POJO did not have a default constructor and had interfaces that were not mapped to concrete classes using annotations